# Content filtering - but allow iframes for embeded content

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following piece of regex to filer content, however I need users to be able to add iframes in the wysiwyg editor, and currently its striping those out, how can I edit this to keep all of its functionality but stop it from stripping out iframes? Thank you

```
$content = preg_replace("%<[a-z]{1,6}[^>]*>\s*</[a-z]{1,6}>%ims","",$content);
```

Comment: Use `"%<(?!iframe\\b)[a-z]{1,6}[^>]*>\\s*</[a-z]{1,6}>%i"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex :

```
$content = preg_replace("%(</?(?!iframe)[a-z0-6]{0,10}[^>]>)%im", "", $content);
```

or better :

```
strip_tags($content, "<iframe>");
```